# Why Am I Not Getting my Expected Output in this basic Op-Amp Circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, preamp, non-inverting

I thought that A = 1 + Rf/Ri for an op-amp non-inverting amplifier? With a 1mV input, I'm getting output voltages in the uVs...
[image]

Comment: The LM741 was obsolete decades ago, please get a better op amp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feedback is incorrect.

As there is 4.5V on positive input, by rules of how op-amps work, there must be 4.5V on negative input too. Which means, there must be about 45V on output, which isn't possible with 9V supply, and the op-amp can't handle supplies beyond +15V anyway.

I bet what you wanted is to have a single-supply circuit with AC coupled feedback to ground, so that only AC component is amplified while DC has gain of 1.

Comment: Thank you! The first part makes a lot of sense. Is this a problem on the buffer too? 

Also, can you elaborate on the single supply circuit? I think I understand it in principle, but I’m not totally sure about the ac coupled feedback part.

Comment: Never mind! Got it! Thank you again for helping me out!